# xcode how to wait until json data parsing?

Tags: xcode, json, uitableview

I'm getting app info from the app store using json url.

I have to parse this file before showing the info in a uitableview.

How can I do that?

I mean waiting until all json wil be parsed and stored in an nsarray.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you begin all the good stuff in `viewDidLoad`.  All you need to do is call the method where you get, parse, and store your data, then just reload the table view afterwards.  Like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    //this is your method where you parse data and put in your array
    [self parseData];

    //this reloads the table view, assuming you have your data source set up
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, in fact I get problems for the method celllForRowAtIndexPath, because the array containing the data that I want to show in the tableView, isn't already fetched. So how can I let the tableView "wait" until the parsing is finished? this code make a long loop (nslog) then crashs.

Comment: Whoops, didn't see this!  In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you should make sure the array isn't nil before you configure it.  To help you further I'll need to have more code, otherwise I won't know exactly what's wrong.